Travelport version 52 results to performance degradation
My system was working fine with V45 of travelport.
When I upgraded the schema to V52, the responsetime of application has increased.
Upon checking with Travelport, they informed that responsetime from their side is as usual.
Anybody facing such issue with V52 schema?
I tried re-generating the wsdl file with Apache CXF 3.1.16, but no luck so far
